# Using PHPUnit as Symfony 2 dependency

Tags: symfony, cygwin, phpunit, composer-php

I'd like to use PHPUnit to test my Symfony 2 applications. I added PHPUnit to my Symfony 2 project `composer.json` file as described in the [documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html#installation.composer):

```
"require": {
        ...
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
```

How can I call PHPUnit now to run tests? I tried to run it via

```
$ php /path/to/symfony2app/vendor/phpunit/phpunit.php
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\...\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 45

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.;\...\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\...\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 45
```

I guess it is a problem with PEAR missing, but shouldn't PEAR be a dependency in PHPUnit and be installed via `composer update`?

Comment: Just as a note: Usually you want to "require-dev" phpunit as you don't want to install it in production (if you that via composer) or if you are a lib/module/bundle you don't want to make other people install phpunit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Composer creates references to the binaries (executable scripts) of the packages it installs inside the so-called "bin-dir". By default, it is located in `vendor/bin/`, so you would run it as such: `php vendor/bin/phpunit`. You can usually just call `vendor/bin/phpunit` too, it should know to execute it with php.

Under Cygwin it might be necessary to call the .bat file directly, as `vendor/bin/phpunit.bat`.

If you would rather have this more accessible, you can add this to your composer.json:

```
    "config": { 
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    }
```

Then the file would become accessible as just `bin/phpunit` within your project, a bit shorter and less hidden.

Note that none of this is really cygwin specific, it should also work fine under the regular windows cmd and on native unix environments.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! On Mac OS 10.8 I can call it just as you said, via `vendor/bin/phpunit`, but on Windows using Cygwin I get the error `Could not open input file: /.../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit`, but calling PHPUnit via `$ vendor/bin/phpunit.bat` works just fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe a path resolution problem with cygwin. I know it works with gitbash and msys/mingw shells because that's what I use, but cygwin tends to do a bit more hackery with the paths.

Comment: Then maybe just add a note to the answer that using the .bat file is the way to go with cygwin. I'll edit the title of the question, because your answer also applies to other systems.